# Volume element in radial integration

Tags: scattering, coordinate-systems, integration

I am reading the quantum scattering book by Taylor. He pointed out that since we are not observing the magnitude of incoming momentum we integrate over it. Then he replaces the volume element $d^3p$ with $d\Omega~p^2 dp$. Actually I don't understand the reasoning behind this replacement. Can anyone help me on this?

I attached the scan of the related page in the book. [image]

Comment: Can you add a picture? I have no clue what you're talking about.

Comment: @YashasSamaga I attached a scan of the relevant page in the book.

Comment: He first writes the volume element in Cartesian coordinates for clarity and simplicity $\mathrm{d}^3p$, and then in spherical coordinates for ease of calculation $p^2\mathrm{d}p \,\sin\theta\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\phi$ which is often written $p^2\mathrm{d}p\,\mathrm{d}\Omega$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may parametrize momentum space in spherical coordinates $(p,\theta,\varphi)$. The volume element in this coordinates may be computed from the Jacobian $J$ of the transformation between Cartesian coordinates and the new ones:
\begin{equation}
  dV=dp_xdp_ydp_z=Jdpd\theta\varphi
\end{equation}
Now, from $p_x=pc_\varphi s_\theta$, $p_y=ps_\varphi s_\theta$ and $p_z=pc_\theta$ (where $s_x=\sin x$ and $c_x=\cos x$) it is straightforward to derive $J=p^2 s_\theta$. Defining $d\Omega=\sin\theta d\theta d\varphi$ we get:
\begin{equation}
  dV = p^2 dp d\Omega
\end{equation}